# Calling a constructor as a method

Tags: c++, constructor

When I call a constructor like this Class::Class() is that operation considered a simple function call or does it imply something else?

```
struct Point
{
   Point()
   {
      X = 100;
      Y = 100;
      cout << "Point ctor !\n";
   }
   int X;
   int Y;
};
```

When calling the constructor in the main, modifying X and Y implies that there is an existing object in memory, am I right? So what does the instruction below really mean? Creating an object with two fields on the stack? So it is not a simple function call?

```
int main()
{
   Point::Point();
}
```

Comment: Since this isn't legal syntax in C++, and a compliant implementation would reject it, your question becomes pretty meaningless.

Comment: Your question is unclear: the object will be stored on the stack AND will have its ctor called. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @ABuckau: **IFF** you use legal syntax, e.g. `Point p;`.

Comment: @IInspectable Obviously. I think your first comment made that pretty clear.

Comment: @IInspectable: Looks legal to me.

Comment: @LokiAstari, [no, it isn't](https://ideone.com/zWu7ul)

Comment: It worked with mine: `g++ 4.2.1`

Comment: "creating an object with 2 fields in the stack ?" ..yes and no; that does happen, but it is not done directly by that  line of code..it is done as part of 'main' (the function 'prologue'), where stack space is allocated for local variables. The ctor is then given a memory address in this space where it can create/initialize the object.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Seems to depend on what compiler you are using: https://ideone.com/9ZZyLQ

Comment: @StoryTeller: Can't find anything in the standard for or against using a qualified-id of a constructor in this situation. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem my compiler is out of date:

```
Point::Point();  // Is illegal.
```

But

```
Point(); // Is fine.
```

> When calling the constructor in the main, modifying X and Y implies that there is an existing object in memory am I right ?

Yes. It creates a temporary object. The temporary object goes out of scope at the end of the expression (in this case ';') at which point it is destroyed.

> so what does the instruction below really mean ?

It is a way of creating a temporary object in an expression. Though you usually don't bother specifying the class name.

> creating an object with 2 fields in the stack ?

That's undefined. It creates a temporary object (which is an object with automatic storage duration) with two fields. There is no such thing as a stack defined for the C++ language so the concept has no meaning.

> so it is not a simple function call ?

Yes the constructor is called to initialize the temporary object.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << Point().Y; // Access the member of the temporary.
}
```

Comment: [GCC seems to object](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a030cfa79f1bc62). Do you happen to have a reference that (explicitly) explains, why this is legal, what it is, and what it does?

Comment: @IInspectable: Mine compiles fine. Default version on the Mac.

Comment: @IInspectable [Clang is fine with it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df1ed6b0999f2356). I'm a bit baffled that such a simple construct triggers a compiler bug, but I seem to remember issues with injected class names from one of them.

Comment: @Quentin: MSC 14 is also happy to compile it. I still believe this isn't legal, but I'd like to know why (or why it is legal). Either way.